# Redux: updating state and scrolling performance problems

Tags: javascript, performance, scroll, redux, react-redux

I could use some help with performance problems in a React + Redux app I am building.

I have a container component (a route) that receives some properties that have been memoeized using 'reselect'.

The route is per User and a User has many Recordings. The selector is just the recordings (objects) sorted by date descending and kept in an array.

The problem is that as a user scrolls through the list of recordings, I have some actions that need to fire. Each one that fires really makes the scroll terrible. The really strange thing is this happens *even if the state change doesn't cause a re-render*. I know this because I had `shouldComponentUpate()` always return false for the part of the render tree that would be updating and the jittering and jumping happens anyway.

I am going to try normalizing the recordings, which are currently an array nested within the user object, but am skeptical this will help. I say this because both actions that are dispatched and cause the scrolling issue are doing very simple updates to state--one simply updates a value at the top of the state tree (for that route) and the other pushes a new value into an array also at the top of the state tree. When I simply comment out these dispatches but do all the logic preceding these dispatches I get perfect scroll performance.

I wonder if I should simply not be trying to perform these state updates while a user is scrolling and should only perform them once scrolling ceases.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So, I ended up solving this. The main way to fix it was to stop updating the redux state container while scrolling and just keep state in local component. Now it's super smooth and almost as little jank as you'd have in a native app.